# How to redraw on a line in Tkinter canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have some lines in tkinter canvas, and also have their code. I want to make them red but not instantaneously, and I want to another line(red line) on them but it should take different time. For example for one specific line it should take 3 seconds that line get red for another one it should take 7 seconds to make that red. It is like drawing another red line on the previous one.

```
   def activator(self, hexagon, duration_time):
        if not hexagon.is_end:
            self.canvas.itemconfigure(hexagon.drawn, fill="tomato")
            self.canvas.itemconfigure(hexagon.hex_aspects.outputs.drawn, fill="tomato")
```

For example I want my hexagon which created by create_polygon method of tkinter get red but not immediately. It should do regarding to duration_time which is the a second variable. I mean it should be done within duration_time second (let say 3 seconds). 
Is there any way for doing this? I have lots of object in my canvas which should get red during an specific time. line, circle, polygon..

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. To improve this question show us what you have done. Show source code and describe what it is doing and what you need it to do. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: thank you, it doesn't matter, it can be either of them, I just want to make it red but I didn't want to make it red in a In the blink of an eye, it should take some times(let say 4 seconds) it can be done by redrawing or anything else but I don't know how?

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you could just draw over it and have a function for drawing over each for a different amount of time:

```
import time
def redraw(delay, color, canvas):
    time.sleep(delay)
    #some parentheses are for the arguments
    (canvas).create_(shape)(blah, outline=(color), fill=(color))
```

for every shape, but for lines, you do not do the fill argument.

Comment: While this does address the issue of different times, incorporating a time.sleep() into a GUI loop, especially for multiple seconds, will cause the main thread to pause for that length of time and freeze the application. Instead, schedule the redraw using <tk_object>.after().

Answer (score -1):

To draw things in the canvas, use the create methods to add new items.

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

w = Canvas(master, width=200, height=100)
w.pack()

w.create_line(0, 0, 200, 100)
w.create_line(0, 100, 200, 0, fill="red", dash=(4, 4))

w.create_rectangle(50, 25, 150, 75, fill="blue")
```